# Unambiguous grammars with different right and left hand derivations

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I read recently that for an unambiguous grammar the left hand derivation need not necessarily be equal to the right hand derivation. Can someone give an example of this?

Comment: Where did you read it? Perhaps they gave examples?

Comment: Leftmost derivations are generally different from rightmost derivations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following simple grammar:
$$
S\to AB \\
A\to a \\
B\to b
$$
Here is a leftmost derivation of $ab$:
$$
S\to AB \to aB \to ab
$$
Here is a rightmost derivation of $ab$:
$$
S \to AB \to Ab \to ab
$$
You can see that they look different. However, they correspond to the same parse tree:

[image: Syntax tree generated using http://mshang.ca/syntree/]

More generally, each leftmost derivation corresponds to a parse tree, and this correspondence is a bijection; and the same holds for rightmost derivations. Therefore each leftmost derivation has a corresponding rightmost derivation, sharing the same parse tree.

Comment: Hi so for a grammar to be unambiguous, they have to have the same parse tree, but are allowed to have different derevations to get to that parse tree.

Comment: A grammar is unambiguous if every word in the language has exactly one parse tree. This is the usual definition. You can obtain equivalent definitions by replacing "parse tree" with "leftmost derivation" or with "rightmost derivation".